# FB.Event.subscribe like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'd like to know how replace *('like '+href)* with a custom hyperlink.
For example: "thank you to like us. Visit example.com"

```
<html>
<body>
 <fb:like href="http://www.example.com/" show_faces="true" width="450"></fb:like>
 <div id="fb-root"></div>
 <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/it_IT/all.js#xfbml=1"></script>
 <script>
   FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(href, widget) {
     alert('like '+href);
   });
   FB.Event.subscribe('edge.remove', function(href, widget) {
     alert('dislike '+href);
   });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that's all you want to do, simply replace the string `'like '+href` with `'Thanks for liking our page, please visit our site at whatever.com'` - otherwise it's not clear what you're asking.

If you want to redirect the user, just use a standard javascript redirect in place of, or on the line after, the `alert();` call

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Can I make ww.example.com an hyperlink?

Comment: in an `alert()`, no, it won't be clickable, but you could use a lightbox or other javascript effect to render a rich dialog, theres too many possible ways to do this for me to recommend one; it depends on your design and other libraries